# Rails 3 listing all users by week of created_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This works on the rails console (rails c) but when seen from browser it does not, it just not shows the results, no errors.

on controler i have:

```
def weekly_user_stats
    @created_users = User.where("username IS NOT NULL")
    @created_users_by_week =  Hash.new{ |h,k| h[k] = [] }
    @created_users.each do |u| 
      unless u.nil?
          @created_users_by_week[u.created_at.beginning_of_week.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")].push("#{u.username}")
        end
      end
  end
```

on views I have:

```
%ul
    = @created_users_by_week.keys.sort.each do |k|
      %li
        = puts "#{k} :  #{@created_users_by_week[k]}"
```

on the page results I only see the keys but not the values inside the keys that shoul be an array of users..
on the console works just fine..
what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't the view look more like this?

```
%ul
    - @created_users_by_week.keys.sort.each do |k|
      %li #{k} :  #{@created_users_by_week[k]}
```

See: http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html

Comment: ops! thanks that worked! first time using halm usually I do play .erb

Comment: how will I go on haml to create a select form based on the hash to stout the array of users? no need for the solution only a tip thanks

Comment: You would output the form tag helper methods with `=`. Something along the lines of `= select_tag model, your_hash, options` - search for FormTagHelper on select_tag usage. p.s. If the answer above worked, mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, Anomalous, done, ps I got the dropdown to work but I cant do anything from it.. in my mind I had something like depending on which week I select it will show the content of the hash(the array of users for that week) below, maybe with a render: so not sure if select_tag will be the best for this or not but if it is Im stuck trying to find an example on how I will go about this.

Comment: If you need the content to change every time a new selection is made you're going to need JavaScript added to the mix. You would have your JavaScript make an AJAX request to a custom controller action that will send back the hash content for a given key. Or load all of the Hash content in hidden divs or as JSON objects and selectively display them based on the `change` event in jQuery. A non-instant alternative would be to have a submit button that goes to another page and displays the appropriate content.

Comment: cool thanks, I remember using prototype with rails 2.x I know that changed on rails 3.x what will be the right framework to use in your opinion? but still obscure to me where does my selection gets save to? to be able to play with it..knowing this I could pass that somewhere and render a _second page that will show the right array?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with haml so I don't know about your specific issue. However I would suggest you to store a different date in your database in order to retreive quickly your created users by week (or even month if you wanted).

You could do that by storing an array as an attribute containing this things:

```
dates = ['20120307', '201203', '2012', '201210']
```

With

```
dates[0] # (yyyymmdd)
dates[1] # (yyyymm)
dates[2] # (yyyy)
dates[3] # (yyyyww)  ww = week number
```

Then you could retreive users by querying on the dates attributes that includes '201210'.